# How to select an element in the ListViewer

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm trying to find and select an element in the `ListViewer`, I compare a string with every element in the `ListViewer`.

I can get the index of the element but I don't know how to select it in the `Listviewer`.

```
String pattern = elementText.gettext();
String[] listViewerValues = mListViewer.getList().getItems();
List<String> valuesList = Arrays.asList(listViewerValues);  
int index = -1;

for(int i=0; i < valuesList.size(); i++) {
    valuesList.set(i, valuesList.get(i).toLowerCase());
}

index = valuesList.indexOf(pattern);
if(index>-1) 
{
    ***....... what to do here ?*** 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [`setSelection(ISelection, boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/StructuredViewer.html#setSelection%28org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection,%20boolean%29) to set the selection.

This will select the element at `position`:

```
mListViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(mListViewer.getElementAt(position)), true);
```