# How can I get a selected Item from a ListViewer in java

Tags: java, listview, swt

I have implemented a ListViewer. This ListViewer is filled with some values. When the user selects a value from this ListView, this value should be compared with a database. My Question is, how can I get this selected value.

```
list.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        DBConnection.ReadCommitMessageTable(list.getToolTipText().toString());
        System.out.println(list.getData().toString());
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how I can get the value?

Comment: Does it do anything as it is now? Are there any errors? I also think you need to implement the `widgetDefaultSelected` method of the `SelectionListener` interface. [API.](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FSelectionListener.html)

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799029/how-to-select-an-element-in-the-listviewer) might help you.

Comment: The code snippet uses an SWT `List` widget whereas the title and text talks about a JFace `ListViewer`. Which one are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onContextItemSelected function

You can find more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: The question is about SWT/JFace, not Android.